# Quantum phase space volume conversion

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-space

Suppose we have some ensemble specified by the energy $E,$ particle number $N$, and volume $V.$ A classical phase space surface area can be calculated from this:

$$\mathcal{S} = \int^{'} d \mathcal{V}= \int^{'} d^{3N}q d^{3N}p$$

Where the prime indicates that the integration extends only in the region:
$$\mathcal{H}(q,p) =E.$$

Oftentimes, an energy range is considered instead, so that a classical phase space volume can be calculated:
$$\mathcal{V} = \int^{'} d \mathcal{V}= \int^{'} d^{3N}q d^{3N}p$$

Where the prime indicates that the integration extends only in the region:
$$E-\frac{\Delta}{2 }\leq \mathcal{H}(q,p) \leq E + \frac{\Delta}{2}.$$

Now let $\Gamma$ be the number of microstates accessible to the system in this energy range, which is calculated from quantum mechanics. We wish to find the size of a "fundamental volume," so that asymptotically,
$$\Gamma = \mathcal{V}/\mathcal{V}_0$$
It turns out that this desired conversion factors is equal to
$$\mathcal{V}_0 = h^{\mathcal{N}}$$
where $\mathcal{N}$ is the number of generalized position coordinates.

My question is: why do we consider the conversion factor between volumes, and not between surface areas? That is, what about finding the size of a "fundamental surface area,"

$$\Omega = \mathcal{S}/\mathcal{S}_0,$$

where $\Omega$ is the number of microstates accessible to the system at this precise energy value?

Furthermore, is there anything special about considering an energy range, rather than a particle range, or a volume range?

---

Edit:
Consider the concrete example of a $N$ harmonic oscillators, with a total fixed energy $E$.

Every oscillator has at least $\frac{1}{2}
\hbar \omega$ of energy. So there is $\frac{N}{2}\hbar \omega$ worth of energy which is not free to redistribute. Let $\tilde{E}=E-\frac{N}{2}\hbar \omega.$ Then we just need to consider the number of ways that $\tilde{E}$ can distribute into a set of $N$ oscillators, where the allowed energy values of the oscillator are $n\hbar \omega.$ We assume that the particles are distinguishable. Then

$$\Omega = {N+\tilde{E}'-1 \choose \tilde{E}'} = \frac{(N+\tilde{E}'-1)!}{\tilde{E}'!(N-1)!}$$
Where $$\tilde{E} = \frac{E}{\hbar \omega} - \frac{N}{2}.$$
So
$$\Omega(E) = \frac{(\frac{N}{2}+\frac{E}{\hbar \omega}-1)!}{(\frac{E}{\hbar \omega} - \frac{N}{2})!(N-1)!}.$$
Next let $\Gamma(E, \Delta)$ denote the number of microstates that lie within an energy range $(E-\frac{\Delta}{2}, E+\frac{\Delta}{2})$ where $\Delta \ll E.$  The exact expression for $\Gamma(E, \Delta)$ would be
$$\Omega(E-\frac{\Delta}{2})+\Omega(E-\frac{\Delta}{2}+\hbar \omega) + ... + \Omega(E+\frac{\Delta}{2}-\hbar \omega) + \Omega(E+\frac{\Delta}{2})$$
If we approximate
$$\Omega(E) \approx (E/\hbar \omega)^{N-1}/(N-1)!$$
Then
$$\Gamma(E, \Delta) \approx \Omega(E) \cdot \rm number\ of\ energy\ steps\ in\ \Delta$$
$$\Gamma(E, \Delta) \approx \Omega(E) \cdot \frac{\Delta}{\hbar \omega}$$
$$\Gamma(E, \Delta) \approx \frac{E^{N-1} \Delta}{(N-1)! (\hbar \omega)^N}$$

Next consider the volume of the relevant region of phase space. Our Hamiltonian is:
$$\mathcal{H}(q_i,p_i) = \frac{1}{2}k\sum_{i=1}^N q_i^2 + \frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^N p_i^2$$
Where $\omega^2=\frac{k}{m}$
$$\mathcal{H}(q_i,p_i) = \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2\sum_{i=1}^N q_i^2 + \frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^N p_i^2$$
The equations of motion are given by
$$q_i = A_i \cos(\omega t + \phi_i)$$
$$p_i = -m\omega A_i \sin(\omega t + \phi_i)$$
Therefore,
$$\mathcal{H}(q_i,p_i)=\frac{1}{2}k\sum_{i=1}^N A_i^2\cos^2 + \frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^N m^2\omega^2 A_i^2\sin^2$$
$$\mathcal{H}(q_i,p_i)=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2\sum_{i=1}^N A_i^2\cos^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^N m\omega^2 A_i^2\sin^2$$
$$\mathcal{H}(q_i,p_i)=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2\sum_{i=1}^N A_i^2=E$$
To find the volume of phase space we take the integral
$$\int \int ... \int dp_1 dq_1 ... dp_N dq_N$$
But here the integration is restricted to the region
$$\mathcal{H}(q_i,p_i) = \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2\sum_{i=1}^N q_i^2 + \frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^N p_i^2 \leq E$$
This is just the volume of a $2N$ dimensional ellipse, with axes $\frac{m \omega^2}{2E}$ and $\frac{1}{2mE}.$ The volume of a $2N$ dimensional sphere of radius $E$ is
$$\frac{\pi^N}{N!}E^N$$
For an ellipse, we need to modify this as
$$\left(\frac{2}{k}\right)^{N/2}(2m)^{N/2}\frac{\pi^N}{N!}E^N \to \left(\frac{2\pi}{\omega}\right)^{N}\frac{E^N}{N!}$$
The volume of the shell is therefore
$$\left(\frac{2\pi}{\omega}\right)^{N}\frac{E^{N-1}}{(N-1)!}\cdot \Delta.$$
We divide this by $\Gamma(E, \Delta)$ and see that the conversion factor is precisely $h^N$.

---

Question:
Why did we need to consider the energy range $\Gamma$ here? What would have been wrong with just considering the surface area at fixed energy $E$ and the number $\Omega.$

Comment: It turns out that in very high dimensions the difference between a thin surface's volume and the volume contained within the surface is negligible. Some author (I can't remember who) quipped that very high dimension are subject to a perpetual potato famine, since in very high dimensions a potato is basically all peel.

Comment: This is also why we often consider the total number of states within a surface of energy $E$, denoted $\Omega_0(E)$, when determining the entropy rather than the number of states within $\delta E$ of the surface of constant energy, denoted $g(E)\delta E$, where $g(E) = \frac{d\Omega_0(E)}{dE}$. This is because $\log(\Omega_0(E)) \approx \log(g(E)\delta E)$.

Comment: There's definitely a difference, it is just negligible for large N in the case of the entropy (log of number of states)

Comment: In the microcanonical ensemble the number of states within $\delta E$ of the surface of constant energy $E$ is the "correct" thing to look at. But then you have to deal with the fact that your entropy seems to depend on $\delta E$. I think this is explained pretty well in Kubo's book on statistical mechanics. It is also explained somewhat in Landau's book, but much less well in my opinion.

Comment: The problem is that if you were really looking at an *exactly precise* energy value there would be zero  states at that energy. There has to be some thickness to the surface to have a volume in phase space.

Comment: In your question you seemed to be working with classical phase space, for which the states are not discrete, and any point or surface would have zero volume. In a classical phase space we introduce an *ad hoc* factor of $(2\pi\hbar)^N$ functioning as the "unit volume" as well as an *ad hoc* "Gibbs factor" of $N!$ to account for identical particles. In your comment you are now talking about discrete energies and states. One of the reasons I'm commenting instead of trying to answer is that I'm not sure exactly what the question is. Maybe you could re-write the question a little...

Comment: As a quick example, if you have $N$ non-interacting hydrogen atoms, then there are 2N electronic states at exactly energy -13.6eV, but there are zero at -14 and zero at -13.

Comment: OK. I will check back later. Maybe someone else will answer too

Comment: @hft I have edited it, feel free to delete your comments if you wish